# Error while downloading pre trained weights for yolov3

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolo

I am trying to download the pretrained weights in order to train yolov3 model on custom dataset but i encounter the following issue. I have mounted drive successfully.
Can anyone help?

```
/content/drive/My Drive/TrainYourOwnYOLO/2_Training

Downloading Raw yolov3.weights

python3: can't open file '/content/drive/My': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Downloaded Raw yolov3.weights in 0.1 seconds

2020-09-18 17:11:36.540071: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] 
Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
Loading weights.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 286, in <module>
    _main(parser.parse_args())
  File "convert.py", line 85, in _main
    weights_file = open(weights_path, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'yolov3.weights'66
```

Comment: Seems like it is not finding the file `yolov3.weights`, check your paths, maybe something is wrong there.

Comment: I have provided correct paths, i don't understand what else could be the problem

Comment: I think the problem is this line on yolo.py:

        homedir = os.path.expanduser("~")


It doesnt find the folder in your home dir, so it throws an error.

Go to your : "os.path.expanduser("~")" and see if it has the folder "'.torch/models/" if it doesnt exists, creat it and try again.